# Disable custom input in HTML input dropdown

Tags: html

Good day!
I've got a simple problem, and it involves HTML.
I've googled everywhere, but found only similar results for, "How to disable autocomplete on input".

I'm trying to find a way to block custom input for a dropdown selection input, but I can't seem to find it.

I've found the attribute `disabled`, and setting `disabled="true"` on the input completely disables it, which is not my goal.

This is my code, I found it on `w3schools.com`.

I've attached 2 versions of it, un-disabled and disabled.

```html
<!--NOT DISABLED STUFF-->

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input style="margin-bottom:15vw;" list="browsers">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
</form>

<!--DISABLED STUFF-->

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input list="browsers" disabled="true">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "custom input"?

Comment: would using a  ```<select>``` input field be an option for you?

Comment: @NickParsons, users are able to enter and type in their own response, instead of selecting one from the dropdown list.

Comment: @Eisenheim, I'll try that and see how it goes :)

Comment: @Mark Oh, I see. Yeah, it sounds like you’re after the <select> tag

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, thanks to @Eisenheim's comment.

Instead of using `<datalist>` stuff, it works when I use `<select>`.

```html
<form action="default.php">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```